# How to replace fragment in view in ViewPager on Android?

Tags: android, fragment

I have `ViewPager`, `PagerAdapter` (not `FragmentPagerAdapter`) and 2 views. I need to insert few fragments in the second view. The problem is that `FragmentManager.begin().replace(id, fragment).commit()` needs view container id but it can't be found because `PagerAdapter` does it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like on every adapter - change the dataset in PagerAdapter and call

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: No you did not catch. I need to insert fragment in view, not just update view on items changed

Answer (score 0):

You will have your custom layout file as ViewPager Item and you will specify in

```
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
```

method of PagerAdapter. In that you can inflate your custom view and add your fragment inside it.

like:

```
 @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            View layout; 
            LayoutInflater mInflater =  (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (mItems.get(position).type) {
            case TAB_ABOUT:
                layout  = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_pager_item_about, null);
                // Commit your fragment Here. 
// Do check if it is already there to avoid multiple commits.
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView((View)layout,0);
        return layout;          
}
```

To add fragment into view:

```
   FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. I do have View instance and i don't have the problems with using it in ViewPager. The problem is how to insert the fragment in the View